# Using background-image instead of image for the thumbnails of a gallery

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I found a pretty cool gallery here : https://blueimp.github.io/Gallery/

The only thing I'd like to change are the thumbnails : I consider that I might have images with different sizes, and I'd like each thumbnail to have the same dimensions. I was thinking of changing the list of image with a list of background-images, so I could apply that `background-size` property to resize each thumbnail correctly. Is that a correct option? Or can I achieve this with the `img` class?

For example : http://jsfiddle.net/8s8vcdxr/8/

I would have all my thumbnails with the same size but I would be able to have their real size in the slider when clicking on them.

Comment: If you're trying to avoid the black margins the current slider has, yep, I'd use background images.

Comment: I don't think my questions was really clear, I am not talking about the slider but about the thumbnails (view before you click on one of them and open the slider)

Comment: Can you add a minimal replica of your code?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see. Well in the example, they use two images - the small thumbnail image and the big one. You could just crop all your small images so that they're the same size, while allowing your larger images to retain their original dimensions.

Comment: Background images are not the right way to go imo.  You should instead create a container and absolutely position the thumb in the container.  Relying on styling for content is not very semantic.

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for! So let's say I have only one image, I should create my thumbnail applying some css on my img class? That's the word I always forget in english, "crop" ! that's the way to go, thanks!